# Need help to simplify- logic algebra

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

{( ∼p ∨ ∼q ∨ r) ∧ (p ∧ r)} ∨ {p ∧ (∼q ∨ r)}

I started like that and then i have no idea what to do....can anyone give a hint please.

{( ∼p ∨ ∼q ∨ r) ∧ (p ∧ r)} ∨ (p ∧ ∼q) ∨ (p ∧ r)

Book answer gives only a True Value

Also i cant reach the answer for this one as well

∼p ∧ {∼q ∧ (∼p ∨ q)}

∼p ∧ {(∼q ∧ ∼p) V (∼q ∧ q)

∼p ∧ {(∼q ∧ ∼p) V F)

(∼p ∧ (∼q ∧ ∼p)) V (∼p ∧ F)

(∼p ∧ (∼q ∧ ∼p)) V F

(∼q ∧ ∼p) V F

The book answer gives only a False Value

p.s this is not homework, im just trying to run through a discrete structure book before joining uni for a comp science course soon.

Comment: Did you try to apply the distributive rules?

Comment: distributive rule for which one?

Comment: $P \wedge (Q \vee R) \iff (P \wedge Q) \vee (P \wedge R)$ and $P \vee (Q \wedge R) \iff (P \vee Q) \wedge (P \vee R)$.

Comment: yes i understand this rule, but where to apply it in the exercise? im stuck, as you can see from my workings i did use the dristrobutive rule...

Comment: Are you sure these are the book's answers? Because if $P$ and $R$ are false in the first one, then the whole sentence is false; similarly, if $P$ is false and $Q$ is false, the whole second sentence is true...

Comment: yes these are the answers

Comment: They are the wrong answers.  Ignore the book.

Answer (score 1):

> $\{(\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r) \land (p \land r)\} \lor \{p \land (\lnot q \lor r)\}
> \\\{(\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r) \land (p \land r)\} \lor \{(p \land \lnot q) \lor(p\land r)\}$

Just use commutation and association and you are almost done.

$~~~[\{(\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r) \land (p \land r)\}\lor(p\land r)\}] \lor (p \land \lnot q) 
$

Keep going... (here's a hint if you want...)

> PS: Recall the rule of absorption: $(\psi\land \phi)\lor \phi = \phi$

.

> Book answer gives only a True Value

Also, the book gives the *wrong* answer.

---

> $\lnot p \land \{\lnot q \land (\lnot p \lor q)\}
> \\
> \lnot p \land \{(\lnot q \land \lnot p) \lor (\lnot q \land q)\}
> \\
> \lnot p \land \{(\lnot q \land \lnot p) \lor \mathrm F\}$

Up to here is quite okay.  Next, recall that $\phi\lor\mathrm F=\phi$ .

$~~\lnot p \land (\lnot q \land \lnot p)$

What you must do next should be clear.

> The book answer gives only a False Value

Also, the *wrong* answer.

Comment: thank you so much